# Mellin integral representation of Dirichlet series

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, complex-integration, dirichlet-series

Are there any known representations of $D(s)$ a Dirichlet series, or let's say a Dirichlet L-function, of the type
\begin{equation}
D(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
with $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$? Like we have for the Zeta function,
\begin{equation}
\zeta(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
for $\sigma>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} a_n) x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-nx}) x^{s-1}dx$$

To understand what it means in full generality, you should consider the Laplace/Fourier transform of the distribution $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nn^{-\sigma} \delta(u-\log n)$ and apply to it the [convolution theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

The [Perron formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) is then a special case of the Laplace/Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: There is also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Polylogarithm_series_transformations) integral transformation by setting $z \mapsto 1$.